# Hadoop 2.6.0 wordcount example not running

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I was following the instructions found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) and [here](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/#comment-620464).

All web urls are opened properly and then I tried to run wordcount example.
I went into ACCEPTED state .. didn't run.

```
[root@localhost hadoop-2.6.0]# yarn jar /usr/local/deployment/WordCount.jar input output
14/12/05 19:15:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your  platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/12/05 19:15:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/12/05 19:15:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/12/05 19:15:23 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/12/05 19:15:24 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 30
14/12/05 19:15:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:30
14/12/05 19:15:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1417787106330_0001
14/12/05 19:15:26 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1417787106330_0001
14/12/05 19:15:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://local:8088/proxy/application_1417787106330_0001/
14/12/05 19:15:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1417787106330_0001
```

Following output on web interface :

```
User:   root
Name:   wordcount
Application Type:   MAPREDUCE
Application Tags:   
State:  ACCEPTED
FinalStatus:    UNDEFINED
```

Can someone tell me possible reason for the this ??

Comment: post your error logs ...

Comment: possible reason for what? Can you provide more details? What is the output? What input did you use? Jobtracker logs?

Comment: I think you don't have any slot available. If you are on YARN, check Active Nodes and (Memory Total - Memory Used). If you don't have any node (nodemanager) or you don't have enought memory available, your job won't be assigned.

Comment: ´jps´ results and command line used for invocation of wordcount please...